How to combine datasets into a unified data frame?
Second question for my final Google Data Analytics certificate project. I have bike data from 4 quarters (split into 4 data sets) that I believe I have correctly transposed to data frames. However, when I attempt to combine them, I can only get a printed output in console and they are still split up by each quarter and the format is not as usable for cleaning, analyzing, etc- I used method one from this article: https://www.statology.org/merge-multiple-data-frames-in-r/
I was hoping to create a new "document" (maybe a data frame?) in which they would all be grouped together by column (given they share the same column names) and sorted by date- basically that it would look like the original data sets, but with more rows. Even if not in date order, at least all together and I could re-order them myself.
I also saw an article that suggested using the data.table package for larger datasets, however it had no link with details as to the manner in which this could be utilized and I was unable to successfully locate any other usable information: https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/merging-data-r
I keep finding different pieces of information for varying methods of combination, but I cannot seem to locate anything specific to what I'm attempting to accomplish. So, I'm hoping some super smart people here can help me.
I imported each quarter's data into r from a .csv file and converted them to data frames:
Quarter1 <- data.frame(Divvy_Trips_2019_Q1)
Quarter2 <- data.frame(Divvy_Trips_2019_Q2)
Quarter3 <- data.frame(Divvy_Trips_2019_Q3)
Quarter4 <- data.frame(Divvy_Trips_2019_Q4)

Then put them into a list:
Combined_2019_bike_data <- list(Quarter1, Quarter2, Quarter3, Quarter4)
And merged them accordingly:
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), Combined_2019_bike_data)
This did create a "document" labeled Combined_2019_bike_data, but when going to view it, it displays all the combined data into console (as previously stated) and it's quite unreadable. In the original data frames, it's organized by columns from left to right-
trip_id, start_time, end_time, bikeid, tripduration, from_station_id, from_station_name, to_station_id, to_station_name, usertype
(yes, I plan to update these once I have everything combined in the manner I would like it to be).
I'll include output samples:
a) Sample from first section of output:

start_time            end_time bikeid tripduration from_station_id
2019-01-01 00:04:37 2019-01-01 00:11:07   2167          390             199
2019-01-01 00:08:13 2019-01-01 00:15:34   4386          441              44
2019-01-01 00:13:23 2019-01-01 00:27:12   1524          829              15

b) Sample from second section output:

from_station_name to_station_id
Wabash Ave & Grand Ave            84
State St & Randolph St           624
Racine Ave & 18th St           644

c) Sample from third section of output (I've replaced the trip_id with x's for any privacy concerns):

to_station_name   usertype  trip_id
Milwaukee Ave & Grand Ave Subscriber xxxxxxxx
Dearborn St & Van Buren St () Subscriber xxxxxxxx
Western Ave & Fillmore St () Subscriber xxxxxxxx

The difference I can see in the documents is that the original ones in the Environment pane show the title under Data with an example description of "3650069 obs. of 12 variables" and a grid icon to the far right that seems to indicate whatever document type that is. The new one I created instead displays "Large list (48 elements, 366.9 MB)" with no icons.

You need to pass the result of the Reduce function to a new object:
combined_dataframe <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), Combined_2019_bike_data)

or else the result is just printed to console. Since you have many columns, it's difficult to read on console.
Another way of combining your list of dataframes is using data.table:
combined_datatable <- data.table::rbindlist(Combined_2019_bike_data)

